# Need to record values from if Statement. Dont know how to code VBA. if you can, please send me the code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image: image here]

As you can see the , the column under "Aep cost" contains an if statement that matches the month to the month entered in C2 to extract values from "total bill" for the relevant bill. But I lose the values when the month in C2 is changed. I need to record the values into the L column in such a way that they retain those values and don't go back to 0 when the if statement under "aep cost" is not satisfied. They only change if the "total bill" amount changes. I hope the question is clear.

Comment: Why can't you calculate total bill individually?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove the formulas in the range `K12:K23`. You can't use formulas here as they will update automatically. Leave the 2 d.p. formatting in place though.

The following macro (don't forget workbooks with macros need to be saved as .xlsm, not .xlsx!) will place the value found in `K8` into the relevant cell of the `K12:K23` table based on the month value in `C2`.

```
Sub update_AEP_cost_for_month()

    Dim mth As Long, ttl_bill As Double
    
    With ActiveSheet
        mth = .Range("C2").Value
        ttl_bill = .Range("K8").Value
        .Range("K12:K23").Cells(mth).Value = ttl_bill
    End With

End Sub
```

What you need to decide is how to trigger the running of this macro:

I'd probably suggest the simplest way would be to add a shape/button in the `J4` area, label it 'Update' and have the user click it when the update should run.

An alternative would be to use a calculation event - but that might cause problems if `K8` and `C2` aren't always perfectly in sync.